# What are the absolute minimum required Permissions I need to download from Play Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, permissions, google-play-services

I have a tablet I bought for work, and as I don't really need most of the apps on it, I am shutting down and disabling all the Google/Android Services I don't need.

Seeing how I need to download some apps I need for work, I need to know the absolute minimum requirements in terms of Permissions (e.g., do they need access to Files and Media, and Contacts?) and Connectivity (would cutting access, e.g., to Contacts make a difference if I were connecting by Mobile Data or WiFi?) that I need to allow Google Play Store and Google Play Services, as well as any other apps/services that I need to allow at the time I am downloading apps to allow me to install them.

Another really important reason I am doing this, is for security, since thus far, almost every device I have used has been hit by some kind of infection, and I'm hoping that shutting down and disabling Services and Apps I'm not using will making it harder to infect my device.

If there is a general answer that applies to all Android versions, I would prefer that. Otherwise, I am looking for answers that apply to Android 10 and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Play Store has an irrevocable [`INSTALL_PACKAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#INSTALL_PACKAGES) permission that allows it as a system app to install apps without other assistance.**

Based on quick testing by disabling every possible permission on Play Store and Play Services from the app info, it is still possible to purchase, download, and install apps from Play Store.

Referring to the Open GApps [Pico package](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Pico-Package) for the absolute minimum GApps installation:

- Google System Base (invisible?)
- (Google) Android Shared Library: no permissions requested, cannot be disabled
- **Google Play Store**: only requires Files and media
- Google Calendar Sync: unrelated to Play Store
- Dialer Framework: unrelated to Play Store
- (Google) Package Installer: no permissions requested, cannot be disabled
- **Google Play Services**: only requires Physical activity, though unrelated to Play Store, cannot be disabled
- Google Text-to-Speech: unrelated to Play Store
- Android Auto stub: unrelated to Play Store

Note that **this only guarantees app purchase and installation**. Apps that rely on Google Play Services might not work correctly without additional permissions allowed.

---

Additional reading:

- [Would disabling the package installer prevent updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/206356/44325)
- [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5803999/2821954)

Comment: This is really helpful, but now I have to ask: if I am able to download and install apps with these permissions revoked, does that mean a malicious app or attacker might be able to do that too?

Comment: @user_dn34297 unlikely but possible. Play Store has an irrevocable `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission that will only work as a system app. (Ref: [Would disabling the package installer prevent updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/206356/44325), [Install apps silently, with granted INSTALL_PACKAGES permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5803999/2821954))